# FastAPI Huggingface Inference every request increases CPU RAM usage

Tags: fastapi, huggingface-transformers, huggingface

We have a FastAPI server, and try to use a pretrained HuggingFace model for inference (on a vast.ai gpu server). The Inference accepts one or many images, and returns an array with the image links provided and the processed output. Neither FastAPI nor the HuggingFace inference were modified beyond what we think is "normal". It works as expected, but only for a limited number of calls. With every request made to FastAPI, the RAM usage increases up to the point where all machine RAM is consumed and the entire service becomes unusable (after hundreds / thousands of requests), and must be killed and restarted.

FastAPI code (started with these parameters uvicorn router:app --port 8000 --host 0.0.0.0)

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI
import image_captioning
from .common import Predict, process_data

app = FastAPI()

model = image_captioning.ImageCaptioningService()


@app.post("/predict")
async def image_captioning(predict: Predict):
    data = predict.data
    return model.run(data)
```

And this is the class which processes the image links provided, started with these parameters `uvicorn image_captioning:app --port 8001 --host 0.0.0.0`

```py
from io import BytesIO
from transformers import pipeline, ViTImageProcessor, VisionEncoderDecoderModel, \
    AutoTokenizer

from helper import get_image, measure_time, get_cuda_device
import logging

class ImageCaptioningService():
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.model_name = 'nlpconnect/vit-gpt2-image-captioning'
        self.extractor = ViTImageProcessor.from_pretrained(self.model_name)
        self.model = VisionEncoderDecoderModel.from_pretrained(self.model_name)
        self.tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(self.model_name)
        device_num = get_cuda_device()
        self.predictor = pipeline('image-to-text', model=self.model,
                                  feature_extractor=self.extractor,
                                  tokenizer=self.tokenizer, device=device_num)

    def __predict(self, images):
        preds = []
        for image in images:
            try:
                image = get_image(image)
                preds.append(self.predictor(image)[0]['generated_text'])
            except:
                self.logger.error(f"Image URL raises error {image}")
                preds.append('ERROR. Could not retrieve image.')
        return preds

    def run(self, links: list):
        pred = measure_time(self.__predict, links)
        pred['result'] = [{'url': link, 'prediction': result} for result, link in
                          zip(pred['result'], links)]
        return pred
```

Are we missing out on a call that must be made after each Inference request? This feels like such a basic thing (making Inference requests) yet we can't seem to find information on how to solve this.
The RAM usage increase happens on the ImageCaptioningService btw, we monitored this with `pmap`. Almost every request (to FastAPI) causes the ImageCaptioningService RAM usage to increase by a couple of MBs. This is a problem, because we intend to make thousands of requests.

Every help / hint is greatly appreciated!

Edited to include the cli parameters to launch the services

Comment: Could you include how you start `fastapi`? Faced similar issue with `Flask` and `Gunicorn`, restarting workers seemed to work but took so much time because of the slow model loading.

Comment: The fastapi code is in the above description. Locally, it's in the image_captioning_server.py.

Comment: I meant how do you actually run the code, like `uvicorn image_captioning_server:app`?

Comment: Sorry, thanks for explaining. I start it like this uvicorn router:app --port 8000 --host 0.0.0.0. I updated the description.

Comment: A random and quicker one, 
Try make the cuda device_number to self.device_number as all others in the constructor method and let me know likewise.
It makes it global.